# MYSQL join table on sum in range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have issue with joining table, these table dose not have relation with other tables.

tables structure

**users**

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ Name        ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Jon         ║
║ 2  ║ Mark        ║
║ 3  ║ Tom         ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

**Opportunities**

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ user_id    ║ total_price ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 2          ║ 1500        ║
║ 2  ║ 2          ║ 2000        ║
║ 3  ║ 1          ║ 1000        ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**levels**

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ Name       ║ parent_id   ║ min      ║target  ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ 1  ║ Golden     ║      0      ║ 1000     ║  5000  ║
║ 2  ║ golden-1   ║      1      ║ 1000     ║  2500  ║
║ 3  ║ golden-2   ║      1      ║ 2551     ║  5000  ║
║ 4  ║ Silver     ║      0      ║ 500      ║  999   ║
║ 5  ║ Silver-1   ║      4      ║ 500      ║  750   ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

I want to get user level if summation of his opportunities total price in range between level `min` and `target` 
I tried with this query but it's showing error `[HY000][1111] Invalid use of group function`

```
 SELECT
  `users`.`id`                   AS `user_id`,
  `users`.`name`                 AS `user_name`,
  SUM(opportunities.total_price) AS `total_target`,
`levels`.`name`                  As `Level_name`
FROM `users`
  INNER JOIN `opportunities` ON `users`.`id` = `opportunities`.`user_id`
  INNER JOIN `levels` ON SUM(opportunities.total_price) >= levels.min
                         AND SUM(opportunities.total_price) <= levels.target
WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
GROUP BY user_id
```

> Note:I'm using Laravel 5.2

Comment: `SUM` can not be used in `join`. And does `levels` have any relation with other two tables?

Comment: You can't JOIN on the results of a SUM in any database I've ever used.

Comment: No relation between levels table and any of other tables.

Comment: @KenWhite yes, you can join them even if 2 tables do not share a common field. The join expression can be as complex as any where clause. Furthermore, the description of the problem is quite clear.

Comment: @Shadow: Strange that you say that, and then start your answer with *you cannot use an aggregate function directly in a join* (which is **precisely** what I said). And the description may be *quite clear* to you, but it isn't to me, and I said very clearly *unclear to me*.

Comment: @KenWhite you should read the whole answer, not just the first sentence... Plus I never wrote that you can use an aggregate function in a join.

Comment: I applaud Shadow for giving a really good answer on how to accomplish what Ahmed was asking. Too often users come and simply say it can't be done, vote people down and criticize with no constructive insight. Why interject yourself if you don't know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other have already pointed out in comments: you cannot use an aggregate function directly in a join. Join operation happens before the aggregation.

You need to do the aggregation **before** the join - therefore you need to calculate the sums in a subquery. This way you can reference the sums as an ordinary field in the join.

```
select t.*, levels.name as level_name
from levels l
inner join
(SELECT
  `users`.`id`                   AS `user_id`,
  `users`.`name`                 AS `user_name`,
  SUM(opportunities.total_price) AS `total_target`
 FROM users
 INNER JOIN `opportunities` ON `users`.`id` = `opportunities`.`user_id`
 WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
 GROUP BY users.id, users.name) t on t.total_target>=l.min and t.total_target<=l.target
```

However, I noticed that you have a hierarchy of levels. The above query will return both the main and the sub level for each user in separate records.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do it in a single call the following might get you started in the right direction.

Basically the solution is to select from a derived table and join to that instead.

I haven't gotten to test it, so there may very well be syntax errors.

```
select
 c.`user_id`    `user_id`,
 c.`user_name`  `user_name`,
 c.total_target `total_target`,
 d.`Name`       `Level_name`
from
(select
 `id`             `user_id`,
 `name`           `user_name`,
 sum(total_price) `total_target`
from `users` a
join `opportunites` b
on a.ID = b.user_id
group by user_id) c
join levels d
on c.total_target >= d.min
 and c.total_target =< d.target
```